# Movement of sprite using fixed time step

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, sfml

I have this loop:

```
sf::Clock clock;
sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
while (mWindow.isOpen())
{
    processEvents();
    timeSinceLastUpdate += clock.restart();

    while (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame)
    {
        timeSinceLastUpdate -= TimePerFrame;
        processEvents();
        update(TimePerFrame);
    }
    render();
}
```

and in update function I do this:

```
object.speed = object.speed * TimePerFrame.asSeconds();
```

and then I run a method in which I do:

```
sprite.move(cos(sprite.getRotation()*PI / 180) * speed, sin(sprite.getRotation()*PI / 180) * speed);
```

But the problem is that the sprite doesn't move. When I don't multiply speed by TimePerFrame.asSeconds(), it does move. How should I fix it so everything is correct? Where and how to use TimePerFrame variable?

Comment: What you're saying is "speed = speed * time", which doesn't make sense. Speed * time is *distance*. (m/s * s = m; you have m/s = m/s * s). (An old highschool-level physics book is a surprisingly good help for game programming.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object.speed = object.speed * TimePerFrame.asSeconds();
```

This line is reducing the speed every frame until it is 0.

You need to scale the movement distance by delta time whenever you move the object. Try this:

```
float distance = speed * TimePerFrame.asSeconds(); 
sprite.move(cos(sprite.getRotation()*PI / 180) * distance, sin(sprite.getRotation()*PI / 180) * distance);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the meaning of `object.speed = object.speed * TimePerFrame.asSeconds();`.

What it actually does is set your speed to a very low value the first time, because the elapsed time is probably a few ms. The the second time this statement is executed, speed is further reduced. And so on until it reach a value so small that your computer interpret it as 0 and therefore `speed * something` is `0 * something` which always gives `0`.